# Dismissing Popover View with Storyboard Segues

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I've been googling and searching all over stack exchange for the right answer, but I can't seem to find it. What I have is a popover view that is presented via a popover segue, and when a button is clicked inside the popover view, I want it to be dismissed and display a UIAlert. Here is the code I have thus far, with what I have gathered from other answers but dosn't work:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"popOverSegue"]) {
    if ([segue isKindOfClass:[UIStoryboardPopoverSegue class]]) {
        UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *popoverSegue = (UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *)segue;
        self.myPopoverController = popoverSegue.popoverController;
    }
}
}


- (void)methodThatShouldCauseMyPopoverToCloseAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
[self.myPopoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:animated];
NSLog(@"Dismissed");
}


-(IBAction)presentPopoverView:(id)sender {
if (!popOverViewIsShown){
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"popOverSegue" sender:self];
    popOverViewIsShown = YES;
}else {
    [self methodThatShouldCauseMyPopoverToCloseAnimated:YES];
    popOverViewIsShown = NO;
}

}

- (IBAction)logoutMethod:(id)sender {

[self methodThatShouldCauseMyPopoverToCloseAnimated:YES];

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Logout"
                                                message:@"Are you sure?"
                                               delegate:self
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                      otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
alert.tag = 0;
[alert show];

}
```

I'm suspecting that when I call `methodThatShouldCauseMyPopoverToClose` that `myPopoverController` is equal to nil. Any suggestions? Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store your popover like this in your prepareForSegue then place a breakpoint to make sure the method is firing.

```
self.myPopoverController = [(UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *)segue popoverController];
```