# Customizing a "segue-storyboard-popover" - iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uipopovercontroller

I created a popover-segue using "control-drag" in a storyboard. But how do I customize this popover? I'm showing a normal `ViewController` inside this popover, but this does not let me configure the `UIPopover`

Right now it looks like this:

[image]

Lets say I wanted the change the background of the popover itself, or dismissing the popover via a button inside the `ViewController`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19062281/dismissing-popover-view-with-storyboard-segues) didn't work for me at first, but that was just a mistake by me. It works great now!